# Can I push the definition of a remote itself to a remote?

Tags: git

Let's say I have two remotes: `origin` and `upstream`. Is there a way that I can push the object `upstream` to `origin`, so that other people who clone my repo from `origin` will be able to run something like `git fetch upstream` with no additional config needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly.  The configuration information for upstreams, like almost all git configuration, is in `.git/config`, which is not considered "part of" the repository.

You could copy that information to a file and `git add` and commit this file, and provide people with instructions on how they can copy it back to *their* `.git/config`.  Or, you can write a script that uses `git config` to add the upstream configuration, and `git add` and commit the script.  But that's not the same as them automatically getting the `upstream` configuration.

(Git hooks have the same issue: they're not "part of" the repository.  You can write the hooks as actual files in the repository and commit them, but you then have to provide instructions to your users: "after cloning, run this setup script to configure the upstream and some hooks", for example.)